# How can I filtering one specified action's value using facebook insight api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As [Ad Insights doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights) described:

We can use param `filtering` to filter specified AD insights like :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<VERSION>/act_ID/insights?access_token=token&fields=ad_id,impressions&date_preset=lifetime&level=ad&filtering=[{"field":"ad.effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["DELETED"]}]

# filtering=[{"field":"ad.effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["DELETED"]}]
```

to filter the deleted effective_status ad data.

And now I need to filter the specified insight data whose action_type offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart's value is less than 5 for example, 
How can I make this filtering work?

```py
# tried 

filtering=[{"field":"actions.offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart",
"operator":"LESS_THAN",
"value":5}]

# but failed
```

```
   "actions": [
       {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart",
          "value": "5"
        },
```